# Is there an adjective to describe someone who has access to all the facts, news or insider information?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

Looking for an adjective to fill in the blank below:

I was talking to my stock broker. I wanted to say: I am not as **_** as you who has access to all the facts, news and insider information (about the stock).

Comment: Insider information is the kind you're not allowed to trade on. Perhaps you're looking for well-versed, plugged-in, tuned-in, knowledgeable or informed.

Answer (score 2):

You might use *[well-versed](http://thesaurus.com/browse/well-versed)* or phrases like *completely informed*,  *well-informed*, or *thoroughly informed*.  *Expert* is another possibility.

Answer (score 1):

There might be another word you can use, if you modify your sentence slightly.

You could use: ***privy***

> I am not (as) *privy* to stock insider information/facts/news as you are.

Here, privy is an *adjective* that describes how well-informed/well-connected the other person is.

Per [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/privy):

> Privy to: **Sharing in the knowledge of (something secret or
> private)**
>
> *he was no longer privy to her innermost thoughts*

The origin of *privy*:

> Middle English (originally in the sense 'belonging to one's own
> private circle'): from Old French prive 'private' (also used as a noun
> meaning 'private place' and 'familiar friend'), from Latin privatus
> 'withdrawn from public life' (see private).

The [freedictionary's](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/privy) definition closely aligns with your sentence example:

> priv·y  (prv) adj.
>
> 1. Made a participant in knowledge of something private or secret: *was privy to classified information.*
> 2. Belonging or proper to a person, such as the British sovereign, in a private rather than official capacity.
> 3. Secret; concealed.

Comment: Yes; whether 'privy' is modifiable (? as privy as) is debatable, as you suggest by the 'scare brackets'.

Answer (score 0):

As a more informal expression you may use:

[In the know](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/In+the+know):

> - Possessing special or secret information.